# Expand div left with animation causes "shakeness"

Tags: css, animation, transform

I have a div container with left and right sides. When clicking on a button, I need to make the left part bigger towards the left side (you can see an example in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-https-kdvyv)).

The animation does occur, but all the divs are being shaken through the transition.

If I change the container from using `transform` to `top` and `left`, everything is ok, as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-kapitsa-jvt6u).

Unfortunately, it is not a possibility for me in real life, because I use a third-party library which uses "transform".

How can I keep the `transform` property and make the animation fluent?

Comment: When using 'transform'，avoid using height,width,margin,padding transition.Use only 'transform', or Use only height,width,margin,padding ...

Comment: If I don't animate `width`, the width changes instantly and it gets bigger from the right. If I don't animate `transform`, the container jumps instantly to the left. Therefore I don't see how I can avoid animation on either `transform` or `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be used not together `transform` and `width` together

```
margin-left: -??px; transition: margin-left 3s;
```

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
  wrap.className = wrap.className.indexOf('expand') === -1 ? 'wrap expand':'wrap'
})
```

```css
.wrap{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000 inset;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition: width 3s;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
}
.expand.wrap {
  width: 400px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px orange inset;
}
.left {
  margin-right: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red inset;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
  wrap.className = wrap.className === 'wrap' ? 'wrap expand':'wrap'
  let left = document.querySelector('.left');
  left.className = left.className === 'left' ? 'left expand':'left'
})
```

```css
.wrap{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000 inset;
  transform: translate(100px, 50px);
  transition: margin-left 3s, width 3s;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
}
.expand.wrap {
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.left {
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red inset;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 3s;
}
.left.expand {
  width: 100px;
}
.right {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px orange inset;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```